# Pergunta sobre PHP , onde não consigo fazer uma exclusão com uma condição"

Tags: php, mysqli

então não estou conseguindo acertar a respeito de um código de exclusão onde contém uma condição, sendo ela, caso um curso cadastrado, seja uma chave estrangeira na tabela usuário o mesmo não pode ser excluído da tabela curso.

Vou deixar o print das tabelas abaixo e o código da exclusão que não esta recebendo o valor, caso alguém possa ajudar ficarei grato.

Aqui é o código de exclusão:

```
<?php

include "../includes/conexao.php";

$idcurso = $_GET['idcurso'];
$curso = $_GET['curso'];
$usuario = $_GET['usuario'];

$consulta = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE curso = $curso");
$numregistros = mysqli_num_rows($consulta);

if($numregistros == "0") {
    $sql ="DELETE FROM curso where idcurso = $idcurso";
} else {
    echo "<script> alert ('Não foi possível deletar pois se encontra cadastrado um nome ao curso desejado a exclusão:'); location.href='curso.php';</script>";
}
```

abaixo é o print das tabelas.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: qual o problema, que erro aparece?

Comment: Apenas , vai para ELSE, não acha o if, duro que não sei pq!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro é que está faltando a conexão com o banco de dados:

```
$consulta = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE curso = '$curso'");
```

Seu script ficará assim:

```
<?php

include "../includes/conexao.php";

$idcurso = $_GET['idcurso'];
$curso = $_GET['curso'];
$usuario = $_GET['usuario'];

$consulta = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT * FROM usuario WHERE curso = '$curso'");
$numregistros = mysqli_num_rows($consulta);

if($numregistros == 0) {
    $sql ="DELETE FROM curso where idcurso = $idcurso";
    mysqli_query($conexao, $sql); // aqui você deleta
} else {
    echo "<script> alert ('Não foi possível deletar pois se encontra cadastrado um nome ao curso desejado a exclusão:'); location.href='curso.php';</script>";
}
```

Para abrir uma conexão você precisa usar o `mysqli_connect`, assim:

```
$conexao = mysqli_connect( SERVIDOR, LOGIN, SENHA, NOME_DO_BANCO);
```

Comment: Cara consegui, você é o melhor, parabéns!